# want to remove a previously added class and add a new class to the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an frombuilder in which on choosing an option value (from 1 to 12) it adds an col-xs-(1-12) class to an div. But when I want to choose an other option to add some different col-xs-(1-12) class previous class doesn't get deleted.

```
function addGrid() {
    console.log("addGrid Called !");
    console.log($(".grid_cols").val());
    var col_val = $(".grid_cols").val();
    console.log("col_val :" + col_val - 1);
    if ($(".fb-field-wrapper").find('col-xs' + '-' + col_val)) {
        console.log("hasClass ??");
        $(".fb-field-wrapper").removeClass('col-xs' + '-' + col_val);
        console.log("removed class");
    }
    else {
        $(".fb-field-wrapper").addClass('col-xs' + '-' + col_val);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it simply that your use of `.find('col-xs' + '-' + col_val)` on line 6 should have a dot in front of `col-xs` to search for a class rather than an element? e.g. `.find('.col-xs' + '-' + col_val)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also:

- Use a bit of regex to see if a class of pattern `col-xs-<num>` exists
- If yes, remove it
- Add the new class

Here is your code, simplified with the above points.

```
function addGrid() {

    var col_val = $(".grid_cols").val(),
        $wrapper = $(".fb-field-wrapper"),
        matches = $wrapper.attr("class").match(/col-xs-(\d+)/i);

    //See if class 'col-xs-<num>' exists
    if (matches !== null) {
        //If yes, remove that class
        $wrapper.removeClass("col-xs-" + matches[1]);
    }
    //Add Class
    $wrapper.addClass('col-xs' + '-' + col_val);
}
```

**Note:** In your code, `$(".fb-field-wrapper").find('col-xs' + '-' + col_val)` would try to find the children of `.fb-field-wrapper` with the class `col-xs-<num>` whereas you wanted to see if that class exists in the wrapper itself. For that, you'd do:

```
if ( $(".fb-field-wrapper").hasClass('col-xs-' + col_val) ) { ... }
```